# ¿ Como cambiar el color de fondo de varios botones a la vez en windows forms?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, interfaz-gráfica

La cosa es así:
Tengo dos formularios, `Form1` y `Form2`.

`Form1` es el pricipal y tiene 20 botones el cual cada uno representa una mesa diferente de mi restaurante. Al hacer click en cualquier de ellos se abre un `Form2` en el cual se pueden registrar pedidos, etc ... Cada `form2` contiene también un botón de Titulo `Abrir Mesa` el cual necesito que cuando sea clickeado me cambie el color de fondo del botón `MESA 1` en el `Form1`. Si el botón `Abrir mesa` de `MESA 2` es clickeado, entonces necesito que sea ÉSTE y no el de `MESA 1` el que cambie de color, y así sucesivamente.

He creado esto que me funciona solamente para el primer botón, o sea el de `MESA1` pero no logro congeniar algo que ande para todos.
Dejo un poco de código a ver si alguien me puede ayudar.
Desde ya muchas gracias!

```
   // FORM 1

  public void btnMesa1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f2 = new Form2(this);
        f2.Text = "Mesa 1";
        f2.Show();
    }

    private void btnMesa2_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f2 = new Form2(this);
        f2.Text = "Mesa 2";
        f2.Show();
    }

    public void cambiarFondo()
    {
        btnMesa1.BackColor = Color.Green;
    }


       // FORM 2



    public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    double precio = 0;
    double cantidad = 0;
    double subtotal = 0;
    double total = 0;
    Form1 f1 = new Form1();

    public Form2()
    {

    }

    public Form2(Form1 parametro)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        f1 = parametro;
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridViewButtonColumn colBotones = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
        colBotones.Name = "colBotones";
        colBotones.HeaderText = "BORRAR";
        this.Pagos.Columns.Add(colBotones);
    }

    private void txtCantidad_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        precio = Convert.ToDouble(txtPrecio.Text);
        cantidad = Convert.ToDouble(txtCantidad.Text);
        subtotal = precio * cantidad;
        etiquetaSubTotalNum.Text = subtotal.ToString();
    }

    // AGREGA UN PRODUCTO
    private void btnAgregarItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Pagos.Rows.Add(txtID.Text, txtNombre.Text, txtPrecio.Text, txtCantidad.Text, etiquetaSubTotalNum.Text);

    }

    // CALCULA EL VALOR TOTAL DE LA MESA E IMPRIME EL TICKET
    private void btnTicket_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Pagos.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            total += double.Parse(Pagos.Rows[i].Cells["celdaSubtotal"].Value.ToString());
        }

        etiquetaTotalNum.Text = total.ToString();
        total = 0;
    }

    // CIERRA LA MESA
    private void btnCerrarMesa_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    // DIBUJA "BORRAR" SOBRE LOS BOTONES DE ELIMINAR
    private void Pagos_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex >= 0 && this.Pagos.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "colBotones" && e.RowIndex >= 0)
        {
            e.Paint(e.CellBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.All);

            DataGridViewButtonCell celBoton = this.Pagos.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["colBotones"] as DataGridViewButtonCell;

            e.Graphics.DrawString("BORRAR", new Font("Verdana", 8), new SolidBrush(Color.Red),
            e.CellBounds.Left + 3, e.CellBounds.Top + 3);

            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }

    // ELIMINA LA FILA DE ESE PRODUCTO AL HACER CLICK EN EL BOTON "BORRAR"
    private void Pagos_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.Pagos.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "colBotones")
        {
            Pagos.Rows.RemoveAt(Pagos.CurrentRow.Index);
        }
    }

    // CAMBIA EL BOTON DE LA MESA A COLOR VERDE/ABIERTA
    private void btnAbrirMesa_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.btnAbrirMesa.BackColor = Color.Green;
        f1.cambiarFondo();
    }
```

Comment: Utiliza patron de observer

Comment: Un poco más de info ?? Soy nuevo programando ... :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una solución muy sencilla es que cambies tu método `cambiarFondo` para que reciba el nombre del boton que debe cambiar de color, y busque ese botón por dicho nombre. Algo asi:

```
public void cambiarFondo(string boton)
{
    var btn = this.Controls.OfType<Button>().Where(x=> x.Name == boton).FirstOrDefault();
    if (btn != null)
    {
         btn.BackColor = Color.Green;
    }
}
```

Luego, en tu `Form2`, cambia la llamada para que envie el nombre del botón a cambiar:

```
private void btnAbrirMesa_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.btnAbrirMesa.BackColor = Color.Green;
    //no pones suficientes datos sobre como sabes que botón se ha pulsado
    //imagino que debes comprobar en el `sender` para saber que mesa es
    //y obtener "indicemesa"
    f1.cambiarFondo("btnMesa" + indiceMesa);
}
```

No es la mejor solución, yo probablemente optaría por usar eventos personalizados y que cada boton escuchara el evento para saber que debe cambiar de color, pero con esta solución creo que te puede servir.

Un apunte importante. En tu `Form2` tienes la siguiente linea:

```
Form1 f1 = new Form1();
```

Esto está creando una nueva instancia de `Form1` que no se utiliza para nada. Cámbialo simplemente por `Form f1;`, ya que luego almacenas la referencia a la instancia.

Comment: No es la mejor solución, yo probablemente optaría por usar eventos personalizados y que cada boton escuchara el evento para saber que debe cambiar de color, pero con esta solución creo que te puede servir. Creo que deberias almenos dar titulares de ah que te refieres

Comment: @BrunoSosaFastTag el titular es ese, que sería mejor usar un evento personalizado. Ahondar en esa solución creo que resultaría en una respuesta demasiado extensa, pero siempre es posible que cualquiera añada otra respuesta explicando esa opción :)

Comment: Muchas gracias a ambos! Hoy a la tarde voy a probar la solución de Pikoh para ver como funciona!

Comment: Hola Pikoh!! No sé como etiquetarte, espero que me leas ... estoy probando la solución que me pasaste pero me tira error acá:                      btn.BackColor = Color.Green;   Dice que btn no tiene una propiedas BackColor

Comment: @NachoZveDeLaTorre Debes depurar la aplicación para ver que es lo que te está encontrando. En principio, al usar `OfType<Button>` debería devolverte un boton si te da ese error es que no te está devolviendo el control correcto.Por otro lado, esta solución funciona si los botones están directamente en el form. Puede ser que estén dentro de un contenedor como panel?

Comment: @NachoZveDeLaTorre vale, es lo que tiene poner una solución compilando unicamente en mi cabeza. Falta añadir `.FirstOrDefault()` en la consulta que busca el botón. He editado la respuesta para reflejarlo

Comment: @Pikoh, muchas gracias hermano! Veo que la tenés re clara con esto de windows forms :D  La verdad, no sé mucho que estoy haciendo porque es para la facultad y te enseñan lo básico, después uno tiene que hacer su propio proyecto ... Estoy en etapa de aprendizaje aún ... Hoy a la noche voy a probar el código que me diste nuevamente a ver si anda ! Muchisimas gracias por tu ayuda, nuevamente, me es MUY útil